# existence of a function $f\in C_c^{\infty}(A_2)$ s.t. $f_{A_1}$ is constant 1

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, functions, convolution

Let $A_1,A_2\subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ two domains such that $A_1\subset \subset A_2$. Why exists a function $f\in C_c^{\infty}(A_2)$ such that $f_{|A_1}$ is constant 1?

My idea is to define $f=\rho \star \chi_{\Omega}$, where $\chi_{\Omega}$ is a characteristic function of a suitable set, maybe $A_1\subset \subset \Omega \subset \subset A_2$, and $\rho\in C_c^{\infty}(A_2)$ is a convolution kernel. Because then follows: $f\in C_c^{\infty}(A_2)$. But I don't know how to find $\Omega$ (maybe Tietze/Urysohn's lemma?) and how to do it in detail.. How to do it? I appreciate your help.

Comment: Do you have some additional information on $A_1$ and $A_2$? Are they open or closed or arbitrary? Because if $A_1=\mathring A_2$ and $A_1$ equals its closure, there will be a problem. Or maybe tell me what you mean by the sign $\subset\subset$...

Comment: Thank you! $A_1$ and $A_2$ are domains (i.e. open and connected). sorry, I thought "areas" is the correct english word for that. The $\subset \subset$-symbol means "compactly embedded, i.e.  $A_1 \subset \subset A_2$ means that $A_1$ is compactly embedded in $A_2$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactly_embedded .

Comment: Ok thanks. If you knew that the boundaries of $A_1$ and $A_2$ were continuous and $A_1$ and $A_2$ were bounded you could make sense of the distance between them. Say the minimum distance is $\mu>0$. Then you could use $\Omega=A_1+\mu/2$. But otherwise I don't see how you could this in general. Take for example $A_2$ to be points $(x,y)$ in the plane such that $y>1/x^2$ and $x>2$ and $A_1$ similar where $y>1/x$ and $x>2$. Then I don't think you can something about this...